Circular relationship in an UML class diagram

I want to know if I can avoid the circular relationship in this case.
Explanation :
the posts table has a forign key city_id to specify the location of the post(product) and the user also has a city_id to specify where he/she live. Now the user can have an 'a' city and create a post that has a 'b' city and that's logic for me because users can be in a vacation or it can be somewhere far from his/her own city. For the user, by default when he/she logs in for the first time the city is set to null but he/she can assign one to his/her profile. The post is obliged to have a city location.
Do you think there is a way to avoid the circular relationship in this case?
I tried to remove the circular relationship since its a bad practice in most cases, but it seems that in my case,  I can't remove it because it wont have a meaning compared to the concept and how my website works

There is no structural circular dependency issue here, since the 0.. multiplicities allow to break the circle :

Post is associated to City
User can be associated to City
Post is also associated to User
There is no constraint, so Post.User.City and Post.City could be different at any moment in time

That's normal associations, like you will find many more in real life cases, where more than one path can link two instances.
The problem is more behavioral: how to initialize the city of a user (the multiplicity tells us it's optional) and how to determine the city of a post if user has no city. Geolocalization can be an answer. A constraint requiring that user associated to a post must have a city when the post is created is another. So it's more about clarifying requirements.

Thank you for your answer,yes your are right the Post and User can have different City . and same sometimes .so for more explanation,here is how my website works in this section:
so when the user register for the first time the city(city_id column) is set to be null , as you say it's optional it can be set or not. the city of the user is more like about profile not post in the other hand the user when he creates a post he must select city, doesnt matter if he set city to his profile or not .so the idea behind this is to give users freedom to choose differents city for their posts.thanks

@YAS-SER indeed, this is what your model suggests. The two cities are not  related unless you add some constraints. Since this seems to be an important feature, and if you fear that readers could be confused, you could add a comment attached to the post-city association, saying in plain text "the city of the post is independent of the user's city"

Thank you so much sir , i appreciate your response
